# need to display a php sql variable value inside a php

Tags: php, html, sql

I want the 1st line `$mc1` value to display in 2nd line .

1st line :

```
<div id = "score_mdl"><div id = "scml"><?php echo "$mc1"; ?></div><div id = "scmlm">
```

2nd line :

```
<?php if ($mc1 == 10) {echo '<div id = "medalg"> want the value here  </div>'; }
```

i tried the below but no resolution yet

```
<?php echo $mc1 ?>
echo '$mc1'
echo "$mc1"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking to do string concatenation. You dont need a second echo statement:

```
<?php if ($mc1 == 10) {echo '<div id = "medalg">' . $mc1 . '</div>'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this notation -

```
<?php 
    if ($mc1 == 10) {
        echo "<div id = 'medalg'>{$mc1}</div>"; 
}
```

This reduces **concatenation**